# Need help for Forge Viewer and Gyroscope. Need the initial camera position to be fixed to the current view In Bim Model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are working on positioning the camera in the viewer to the position of the gyroscope. This part we got working. For one of our customer  we need the initial starting position of the viewer when activating the gyroscope to be the same direction we are looking at. So when activating the gyroscope, the viewer stays in the same direction (left to right angle), but then when I turn the tablet to the right the viewer turns to the right as well.
The challenge here lays in translating the camera position of the viewer to an alpha offset before the gyroscope is activated.
In the example below you have the function calibrateCompassOffset() that tries to calculates the alphaOffset based on the current camera position. But its now working as intended (when I am viewing the front of a model it will calibrate it to the wrong position). I expect to view the front as well after turning on the gyro.

```
**Below was the code snippet :**
     /**
      * Make sure the given angle falls in between 0 and 360
      *   {number} aAngle
      *  s {number}
     */
   private scaleAngle = (aAngle: number): number => {
    for (let i = aAngle; i < 0; i += 360) { aAngle += 360; }
    for (let i = aAngle; i > 360; i -= 360) { aAngle -= 360; }
    return aAngle;
   }

   //Updating  the viewer camera positions using device orientation positions

      if(this.deviceOrientation.gamma > 0.0){
        this.deviceOrientation.alpha = this.deviceOrientation.alpha-180.0;
      }
let newCameraDirectionAlpha = this._initialCameraDirection.clone().
      applyAxisAngle(this._initialCameraUp, Math.PI * this.deviceOrientation.alpha / 180.0);
      let newCameraDirectionBeta = this._initialCameraDirection.clone().
      applyAxisAngle(this._initialCameraUp,Math.PI*this.deviceOrientation.beta/180.0);
      let newCameraDirectionGamma = this._initialCameraDirection.clone().
      applyAxisAngle(this._initialCameraUp,Math.PI*this.deviceOrientation.gamma/180.0);
      this.viewer.navigation.setTarget(newCameraDirectionAlpha.add(this._initialCameraPosition));
      this.viewer.navigation.setTarget(newCameraDirectionBeta.add(this._initialCameraPosition));
      this.viewer.navigation.setTarget(newCameraDirectionGamma.add(this._initialCameraPosition));
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent some more time playing with the math (source code, gyroscope viewer extension) but with no luck unfortunately... Here's the final state of the experiment:

- Testing app: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/tree/experiment/gyroscope
- Gyroscope viewer extension: [GyroscopeExtension.js](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/blob/experiment/gyroscope/public/GyroscopeExtension.js)

At the end of the extension you can see a couple of methods I tried when applying the angles to the camera direction (`_updateCameraDirectionV1`, `_updateCameraDirectionV2`, ...), last one looking like this:

```js
    _updateCameraDirectionV3(initialCameraDir, alpha, beta, gamma) {
        let euler = new THREE.Euler();
        euler.set(beta, alpha, -gamma, 'YXZ');
        let q = new THREE.Quaternion();
        q.setFromEuler(euler);
        return initialCameraDir.clone().applyQuaternion(q);
    }
```

This logic (inspired by three.js' [DeviceOrientationControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1b4d6ce78fc2933613d457a206ce5104ecf184ea/examples/jsm/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js)) is somewhat close to what you're going for, but still not there. I suspect the issue will be in the actual angles and their order.

One more thing I've found that seems a bit confusing to me is that on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Orientation_and_motion_data_explained it says that the *alpha* value should represent rotation around the Z axis (axis pointing "from the display to the viewer") but in my local tests it looked like *alpha* was actually the rotation around the Y axis (axis pointing "from the center of the device to the top of the device").